# Redirecting output of a python program to input of a cpp program directly

Tags: python, ipc

I have a python program that based on some situations, it outputs 1 or 0.
I have another cpp program (not developed by myself, from a software) that can do neuron stimulating. I want that stimulating happens based on output of my python program (situations where the output is 1).

How we can connect two programs to receive input from each other (in this case, cpp program directly gets input from the output of python program)?

Update:
So my python program is a while loop that wait until an audio comes. If that audio is understandable (the speech recognition system can understand it), the output would be 1. Then I want whenever the output is 1, I send this output to the C program. So i want to avoid inputting C program by hand. Somehow, I am looking for a way to do it automatically.

My operating system is windows.

Is there any way to do it?

If this question is not suitable for this forum, I appreciate to you inform me where can be an appropriate forum to ask.

Thank you very much

Comment: What are the arguments your C program can take, i mean how do you do this "So i want to avoid inputting C program by hand." can you show us the command?

Comment: How does the C program consume input?

Comment: This could be as easy as using the python `popen` module to spawn a subprocess and send data to STDIN, all the way to doing GUI manipulation or worse. We need more information on how the other program accepts input.